# How to connect to DSL in rpm-based distro

Tags: rpm, internet

I need to connect to Internet using terminal. Using Ubuntu I could do it by using "pppoeconf" (it asked me only login and password). How can I do that in rpm-based distros ? What info should I provide to connection utility ?
(preferably openSUSE)

Answer (score 0):

rpm-based distro is very-wide area (RHEL, Fedora, Suse and bunch of others). I will assume Fedora:

```
dnf install NetworkManager-adsl NetworkManager
```

and just open NetworkManager application and follow your instinct. If you do not have GUI available. Then

```
dnf install NetworkManager-tui
```

which provides command `nmtui`.

Comment: How can I do that before I have working internet connection ? I'm interested more about openSUSE.

Comment: You can use Live distribution from USB, and mount your disk and chroot there.

Comment: do you mean that I can install NetworkManager from the disk ?